# SQL Trigger After Update not working

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

please help me...

```
USE `arma3life`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`zoxxen`@`localhost` TRIGGER `money_log` AFTER UPDATE ON `players` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.`bankacc` <> OLD.`bankacc` OR NEW.`cash` <> OLD.`cash` THEN
        INSERT INTO `supportertool_money` (
            `i_player_id`
            ,`i_bankacc`
            ,`i_cash`
            ,`dt_inserted`
        )
        VALUES (
            NEW.`playerid`
            ,NEW.`bankacc`
            ,NEW.`cash`
            ,NOW()
        );
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

There have to be a issue.. I cant Update my rows anymore and the Trigger is not working
I'm using innodb

Comment: Presumably the `if` statement is failing.  If I had to guess why, it is because the values are initially `NULL`.

Comment: But.. The values could be NULL.. I mean someone could have 0$.. Or what do you mean? :)

Comment: YOu need to say what datbase backend this trigger is for. Trigger code is very differnt from datbase to database.

Comment: What do you mean? Its a MySQL Server 5.5

Comment: If values are null then they generally don;t work properly ina comparision. IN SQL serverI woudl use coalse to put anynulls to 0 as part of the comaprison. Not suer how mysql c=would handle but you were asking why the nulls made a differntce and that would be why. NULL is never = to NULL nor can it be > or <.

Comment: Okay. So how could i solve the problem? Never facing a problem like this before... i mean... in php it would be easy..

Comment: I tried some things now but i cant solve it.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement is:

```
IF NEW.`bankacc` <> OLD.`bankacc` OR NEW.`cash` <> OLD.`cash` THEN
```

The conditions do not do what you expect when values are `NULL`.  Try this:

```
IF NEW.bankacc <> OLD.bankacc OR
   NEW.bankacc is null and OLD.bankacc is not null or
   NEW.bankacc is not null and OLD.bankacc is null or
   NEW.cash <> OLD.`cash` or
   NEW.cash is null and OLD.cash is not null or
   NEW.cash is not null and OLD.cash is null then
```

Comment: Mh.. I am able to update it ones but then it fails :(

Comment: I mean ... If it is working one time. Maybe there is a mistake in the sap or something like this :o

Comment: @Architect . . . If it works once, I would be suspicious about the data.